# Is it right to say that "they have their utopia starting when they see a plate of food and water"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, british-english, greek

I have to do a presentation about a third world country next week and I started writing down what I am going to say and I am stuck in the introduction! I am speaking Greek and this phrase make sense in Greek but I think it's not right in English!

> I want to say that they have nothing to eat and nothing to drink and that when they find food or water they feel so good that it's like our utopia!

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical. It is also perfectly nonsensical.

Comment: I can understand what you mean.. I want to say that they have nothing to eat and nothing to drink and that when they find food or water they feel so good that it's like our utopia!

Comment: I am afraid for that you'll need to rewrite from scratch, and we do not do ghostwriting here (it is indeed not a good fit for the Stack Exchange engine as such, because there can be any number of possible rewordings, all subjective). If you stick around to get to 20 reputation points, you can take your question to chat, though. Thank you.

Comment: [utopia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utopia) is a *place* (imaginary). Therefore *where* might be better than *when* with it (except to say one has *reached utopia when*). Perhaps, "where they have food and water, they are in their utopia."

Comment: Wait...are you giving your talk in Greece or Cyprus? And you call either of them 3rd world?

Answer (score 1):

How about :

**A place where there is a plate of food and water, is utopia for them.**